# Problem with GRUB for dual-boot installation of LMDE 2 (and Windows) on encrypted luks-lvm (truecrypt)

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, luks, lmde

I'm trying to install LMDE 2 'Betsy' 64-Bit dual-booting with Windows 8.1 and both systems encrypted separately, Windows with truecrypt and LMDE with luks. When booting I want to be asked for the truecrypt volumes password and when I press Esc GRUB should start and boot the encrypted Linux. I want to have a LVM partition for my data which will be my home directory in Linux and which I plan to access with https://github.com/t-d-k/LibreCrypt . My problem is that I can't get GRUB working.

Most of the following steps I took from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/system_verschl%C3%BCsseln and changed them to fit my needs.

Here is my setup although Windows is not encrypted yet:

```
/dev/sda1 Windows Recovery  ntfs
/dev/sda2 Boot      ext4        300MiB
/dev/sda3 Windows 8.1   truecrypt
/dev/sda4 crypt-luks    crypt-luks
```

And here is what I did:
Boot LMDE 2 from USB stick.
Select German as language.
Do the other stuff until I have to select a partition. There I enter Expert Mode where I get asked to mount my target System under /Ziel but it needs to be /target.

I start to get the system ready with:

```
cryptsetup -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 luksFormat /dev/sda4
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda4 lukslvm
pvcreate /dev/mapper/lukslvm
vgcreate vglmde /dev/mapper/lukslvm
```

Then I create my logical volumes:

```
lvcreate -L 8G -n swap vglmde
lvcreate -L 25G -n root vglmde
lvcreate -l 100%FREE -n home vglmde
```

I format these partitions with labels:

```
mkswap /dev/mapper/vglmde-swap -L swap
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vglmde-root -L root
mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vglmde-home -L home
```

Then I mount the logical root partition in /target to continue installing:

```
mkdir /target
mount /dev/mapper/vglmde-root /target
mkdir /target/boot
mount /dev/sda2 /target/boot
mkdir /target/home
mount /dev/mapper/vglmde-home /target/home
```

Then I continue the installation. When asked I choose that GRUB should be installed in /dev/sda2 because that is my boot partition.

After the dialog Installation paused shows up, I perform the following steps:

```
mount -o rbind /dev /target/dev
mount -t proc proc /target/proc
```

Here I get the message that proc is already mounted on /target/proc

```
mount -t sysfs sys /target/sys
```

Here it says that sys is already mounted or /target/sys is busy.

```
cp /etc/resolv.conf /target/etc/resolv.conf
chroot /target /bin/bash
```

Then I make sure the required packages are up-to-date.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cryptsetup lvm2
```

To set up the /etc/crypttab I first get the UUID and then append to the crypttab replacing  with the UUID.

```
blkid /dev/sda4
echo "lukslvm UUID=<MY_UUID> none luks" >> /etc/crypttab
```

Then I append some necessary modules.

```
echo "dm-crypt" >> /etc/modules
echo "ohci_pci" >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
update-initramfs -u -k all -t
```

And I edit the /etc/fstab .

```
echo "/dev/sda2     /boot   ext4    defaults            0   2" >> /etc/fstab
echo "/dev/mapper/vglmde-root   /   ext4    defaults,errors=remount-ro  0   1" >> /etc/fstab
echo "/dev/mapper/vglmde-swap   none    swap    sw              0   0" >> /etc/fstab
echo "/dev/mapper/vglmde-home   /home/  ext4    defaults            0   2" >> /etc/fstab
```

Then I update GRUB and leave chroot.

```
update-grub
exit
sync
```

And continue the installation.
When asked if I want to reboot I say yes and...
...at reboot I get the following output:

```
error: no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Now I can't figure out where I went wrong. Am I right that GRUB should have loaded normally when there is no other boot-able partition?

P.S. When debugging the following commands let you use the installed system when on a live disc.
Mounting the encrypted Volume

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda4 lukslvm
```

Search and add the volume groups.

```
vgscan
vgchange -a y
```

Mount the volumes as usual

```
mount /dev/mapper/vglmde-root /mnt
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems I was wrong to expect that LMDE should just boot.

When I inserted a truecrypt rescue disc and left the loader by pressing Esc GRUB loaded just fine and I could start LMDE. By restoring the Volume Header in the repair options it works without the disc.

However I didn't manage to boot Windows again so I gave up on the dual boot and switched to virtualization.